# Ctrl+C(/Z) doesn't work on konsole, KDE, but work in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, kde-plasma, ctrl

When I'm in KDE, I can't use Ctrl+c or Ctrl+z to stop a process in konsole, it just shows "^C", but when I use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to a terminal, Ctrl+c works. Why? How to make it works in KDE?
The process I try to stop is wget. 
I'm using kde5, Archlinux.

Comment: Try gnome-terminal, that one works well for me. Or xterm if you don't want gnome dependencies to be pulled in. Maybe others would work but I'm not sure. I'm surprised konsole doesn't implement terminals properly in your case.

Comment: Ctrl+C sends `SIGINT` to all processes to attached to a control terminal. How they would handle this (exit or just dump `^C` to stderr) is up to that programs, so I don't think that there is a problem with konsole itself.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, so you won't get an answer. I would suggest you read about [bug #313862](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=313862), which seems related to your issue.

Comment: The process I try to stop is wget. I think the problem isn't in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's Paul Stelian and  Frédéric Hamidi.  I try gnome-terminal and Ctrl-C works. I find the problem is up to the konsole and yakuake. I remove the 'konsolerc' and Ctrl-C works in konsole. But the problem still exists in yakuake. I'm surprised that a bug in 2013 still produces in today.